# C++ Server / Web client , only initial message runs

Tags: c++, websocket, server, client

Title may be unclear, forgive me. I believe this is a client-side problem and I'm not really familiar enough with websockets. I can successfully initialize my web page with a message from my c++ server by sending concatenated string of following:

**HTTP header**

```
const char * http_header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
          "Content-length: %ld\r\n"
          "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
          "\r\n"
              "%s";
```

**Page Source**

```
const char * html_source = R"(<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<meta name='viewport' content='width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0'>
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content = 'ie=edge'>
...

MY PAGE CODE GOES HERE

...
</script>
</body>
</html>)";
```

**Transmission loop**

```
char browser_init[strlen(http_header)+strlen(html_source)];
sprintf(browser_init,http_header,strlen(html_source),html_source);

const char * test_message = "a";
   while(true)
    {
    if(ping_count == 0){
    connection_status = 3;
    recv(client_socket,client_message,sizeof(client_message),0);
    send(client_socket,browser_init,sizeof(browser_init),0);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
    if(ping_count>0){
    if(send(client_socket,test_message,sizeof(test_message),0)){
        connection_status = 2;
    }
    if(!send(client_socket,test_message,sizeof(test_message),0)){
        connection_status = 1;
        std::cout<<"Connection failed";
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
    ping_count++;
}
```

This first message is successfully initializing my webpage on browser but I cannot receive following ones.

I tried adding the code below inside `<script>` , I no longer see my javascript content and Firefox status bar says : *Transferring data from localhost* (page is continuously loading)

```
    var ws = require("nodejs-websocket");
    var client = ws.createServer(function(conn){
    console.log("New Connection");
    conn.on("message",function(str){
    console.log(str);
    }).listen(12000,'127.0.0.1');
    });
```

I'm literally sitting here and waiting for help at this point

Comment: You try to use `nodejs-websocket` in the webbrowser, and you try call `ws.createServe` there? And how is that be related to your `This first message is successfully initializing my webpage on browser but I cannot receive following ones.` or to the complete question at all?

Comment: `An advice would be better, instead of asking me questions.` Since I'm not allowed to ask you questions to track down your problem and to figure out which part of the question is relevant and which one not, I'm not able to help you.

Comment: @t.niese I totally misunderstood your question, sorry about that. I thought you were asking why I was using nodejs there, I think you are asking why it is server and not client. It's client in my code and server here,my bad. I mean i cannot receive or cannot see any indication that I'm receiving messages in the browser.

Comment: I'm surprised the first message passes through... although the question is missing client-side code, I suspect the client is a browser and expects WebSocket formatted messages. Your messages don't appear to be encoded using the WebSocket protocol format, rather, they appear as raw data (WebSockets != sockets). In addition, your transmission loop (?!) is missing error handling for `send` and `recv` and never polls the socket's state (don't use `sleep`!) - it's not code you should use in anything (not even a toy project).